# How to configure the alignToken for the cases in pattern matching syntax using scalafmt?

Tags: scala, format, scalafmt

In scala using scalafmt and having the following content in my `.scalafmt.conf` file:

```
style = default
maxColumn = 120
continuationIndent.callSite = 2
continuationIndent.defnSite = 2
align.openParenDefnSite = false
align.openParenCallSite = false
danglingParentheses = true
indentOperator = spray
project.excludeFilters = [".*\\.sbt"]
rewrite.rules = [RedundantBraces, RedundantParens, SortModifiers, prefercurlyfors]
unindentTopLevelOperators = true
importSelectors = singleLine
spaces.afterKeywordBeforeParen = true
lineEndings = unix
newlines.penalizeSingleSelectMultiArgList = false
newlines.alwaysBeforeElseAfterCurlyIf = false
binPack.literalArgumentLists = false
runner.optimizer.forceConfigStyleMinArgCount = 1
```

it currently aligns the case arrow token from:

```
object Object {
  def f(s: String): Int = s match {
    case "a" => 1
    case "b" | "c" | "d" => 2
    case "e"=> 3
    case _  => 4
  }
}
```

to this:

```
object Object {
  def f(s: String): Int = s match {
      case "a"             => 1
      case "b" | "c" | "d" => 2
      case "e"             => 3
      case _               => 4
  }
}
```

I don't want the code to align on the arrow in order to minimize whitespace noise in pull requests, especially during renames one one line that would change the indentation level on of the entire block.

Reading [the scalafmt docs](https://scalameta.org/scalafmt/docs/configuration.html#aligntokens) I only find out about the default case:

> **align.tokens** Default: `[caseArrow]`
>
> An align token is a pair of code, which is the string literal of an
>   operator of token, and owner, which is the kind of the closest tree
>   node that owns that token. If no owner is provided, then all tree
>   kinds will be matched.
>
> ```
> x match {
>   case 1  => 1 -> 2
>   case 11 => 11 -> 22
> }
> ```
>
> Config for this example
>
> ```
> align.tokens = [{code = "=>", owner = "Case"}]
> ```

I want to not only disable the alignment but I want scalafmt to ensure that there is one space before and after the `=>` arrow. (So it basically should work in reverse of what it is currently doing.)

How can I achieve that?

Comment: what is your current scalafmt file, so that we can tell what can and cannot be changed. Because if you are fine disabling everything, 'align=none' will work, though I suspect that would break the formatting elsewhere, and would not be an acceptable solution.

Comment: actually, after some quick testing, it appears that the behaviour you want is the default behaviour for case statement arrows, so the fix is to just delete whichever line in your scalafmt file is causing it to try to align them otherwise. Cannot diagnose further without the file however.

Comment: @DavisBroda Sorry for omitting the config, I have added the content to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like there isn't a convenient `align.tokens.remove` method to go with the `align.tokens.add` method, however equivalent behaviour can be achieved by manually specifying the `align.tokens` parameter.

The below lines will - if added to the config - replicate the default align token behaviour for everything but the `case =>` token. It will also not align the `case ⇒` token, which should - unless you are doing something unusual - maintain the same align behaviour as `=>` .

```
align.tokens = [
    { code = "extends", owner = "Defn.(Class|Trait|Object)" }
    { code = "//", owner = ".*" }
    { code = "{", owner = "Template" }
    { code = "}", owner = "Template" }
    { code = "%", owner = applyInfix }
    { code = "%%",owner =  applyInfix }
    { code = "%%%",owner =  applyInfix }
    { code = "<-", owner = "Enumerator.Generator" }
    { code = "←", owner = "Enumerator.Generator" }
    { code = "->", owner = applyInfix }
    { code = "→", owner = applyInfix }
    { code = "=", owner = "(Enumerator.Val|Defn.(Va(l|r)|Def|Type))" }
]
```

The default list of tokens was taken from the source code file [AlignToken.scala](https://github.com/scalameta/scalafmt/blob/08c6798a40188ce69b3287e3026becfbd540a847/scalafmt-core/shared/src/main/scala/org/scalafmt/config/AlignToken.scala), where they are contained in the `default` object.

If you want to remove other token formatting instances, just delete their instances from the map.

Note that if additional default tokens are added in an updated version of scalafmt, you will have to add them manually to this param in your config to get that functionality.

Comment: I assume I should also remove the `{ code = "⇒", owner = "Case" }` case as it is the same thing just for a unicode symbol, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that should also be removed, unless you for some reason want to align the `⇒` symbol differently than the => symbol. will edit that into answer as I would assume most people would want the cases treated identically